# How to retrieve contents on a web page using Java

Tags: java

Can anyone suggest me a way to retrieve contents on a web page page using java?
I need to redirect to a web page, expand a block, and copy certain strings under it. Now I need to feed part of that string into another text box on a different page. How can this be done using java?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Selenium (http://www.seleniumhq.org/). You can look up a tutorial on how to properly implement it for pulling data from websites. Assuming this is your own website, however, you can use a Socket.IO connection to communicate data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Jsoup? https://jsoup.org/ it is a nice library for getting documents, parsing, etc.